# Working with many inputs (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and I need some suggestions on how to deal with having many inputs to a function.

The program reads data from multiple elements and stores them in an array, which I'm doing in a loop. The problem is that if I input the wrong information about one element, I must re-input the data all over again. I believe that there must exist a better way to input these data, like reading it from a external file, for example.

The problem with the external file would be, as far as I know, with the reading of multiple arrays from a single file, hence the need of multiple external files - and I believe also that must exist some better way.

Comment: Your question is very abstract and vague, but it's possible you might be looking for [save](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [load](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @beaker, you can use `save` and `load` to store the data. You can store multiple variables in a given file without a problem.